# iso date and time not giving in the required format

Tags: java, isodate

1. what format should i use to get required output
2. for input "2016-04-01T16:23:19.8995"  o/p=2016-04-01T16:23:19.900 therefore .8995 rounded off to .900 in the output

   3.similarly for input "2016-04-01T16:23:19.9995" expected output is 2016-04-01T16:23:20.000 not getting expected output

---

public class Date {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS");
    System.out.println(sdf.parse("2016-04-01T16:23:19.9995"));

}
```

}

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`S` means millisecond no matter how many `S` you use.

If you want this behaviour, I suggest you

- parse that portion yourself or
- use JSR 310 which can handle nanoseconds in timestamps.

Using the DateTime library in Java 8.

```
String dateTime = "2016-04-01T16:23:19.8995";
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime);
System.out.println(localDateTime);
```

prints

```
2016-04-01T16:23:19.899500
```

if you want to round it you can do.

```
LocalDateTime inMillis = localDateTime.plusNanos(500_000).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
System.out.println(inMillis);
```

prints

```
2016-04-01T16:23:19.900
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, you can use `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-04-01T16:23:19.9995");
System.out.println(time); //gives 2016-04-01T16:23:19.999500 as output
```

LocalDateTime should give you at-least the desired format. 
And as Peter answered, S is milliseconds no matter how many S you use.